# Null checking a generic type

Tags: c#, comparative-review

Assuming I have a method with this signature

```
public void DoStuffWith<T>(T foo)
```

and I want to **allow both structs and classes** to be passed as `T`, I was wondering about how to best do the null-checking in case `T` is a class.

I came up with following two approaches:

---

## 1. Checking whether `T` is a struct or a class at runtime:

```
public void DoStuffWith<T>(T foo)
{
    if(!typeof(T).IsValueType && foo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(foo));
    }

    ...
}
```

## 2. Having two overloads with generic type constraints:

```
public void DoStuffWithStruct<T>(T foo) where T : struct
{
    ...
}

public void DoStuffWithClass<T>(T foo) where T : class
{
    if(foo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(foo));
    }

    ...
}
```

---

However, I dislike both approaches. I don't like the runtime type-checking at #1 and I don't like having multiple, differently named overloads at #2.

**Which of the approaches do you suggest or do you think I should maybe consider a totally different approach altogether?**

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Comment: @Dannnno thank you for the note. I am sorry I created an off-topic question... since there has been an answer already, I cannot delete the question anymore. What do you recommend now?

Comment: At this point no need to do anything. If you have an actual code sample feel free to add that (but don't remove anything as that would invalidate the answer) for additional context.

Comment: @Dannnno as I wanted to add the actual code, I discovered that I made a lapse of thought. Therefore, the whole question is irrelevant and I will try to VTC it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try the following :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo<string>(null);
        Foo<string>("asd");
        Foo<int>(1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Foo<T>(T test)
    {
        if(test == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ho ho it's null");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(test.GetType());
    }
}
```

You will realize that both the options are, excuse me, useless. The language already supports this behavior and if `T` is a `struct`, `test == null` will simply return `false` all the time.